# "javascript:;" tooltip when using gwt widget

Tags: javascript, gwt

I'm using the gwt UlTabBar (com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UlTabBar).
When mouse over this tabbar, a small tooltip in left bottom corner of browser with "javascript:;" label occurs. 
Is there any way to disable this tooltip? (it doesn't look nice)
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reading between the lines here but:

- you are using Chrome, and what you see is the target of a link
- TabBar doesn't use links by default, so it means you're putting those links inside the tabs
- `javascript:;` is generated either by an [`Anchor`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html) with no *href*, or an [`Hyperlink`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html) without *target history token*.

In any case, a link without target is by definition not a *link*. Don't use a link if you mean something else.

Comment: @alex if for some reason you must use links, you can set a nicer href, like href=''. and catch the click event so the link will actually do nothing..but Broyer is right, prefer not using a <a> tag at all.